# Having trouble getting the emitted value from the component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need a datepicker for the app I'm working on. I've chosen one from here https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview.
The code I inserted in my datepicker component is taken from what is right under **Changing the datepicker colors**.

**`datepicker.ts`**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Datepicker palette colors */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-color-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-color-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-color-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerColorExample {}
```

**`datepicker.html`**

```
<mat-form-field color="accent">
  <mat-label>Inherited calendar color</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field color="accent">
  <mat-label>Custom calendar color</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker2 color="primary"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Now I would like to catch the user chosen values. But I don't get how I'm supposed to do this. How does the event get emitted here?

Comment: There seem to be plenty of examples on how to do that here: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

Comment: @R.Richards Oh, lemme check it out.

Comment: @ShashankVivek Well yeah actually R.Richards told me about the docs that I for some reason missed and I did make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `(dateChange)` event

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput
    [matDatepicker]="picker"
    placeholder="Different locale"
    (dateChange)="setDate($event.value)">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<p>{{ date }}</p>
```

[here is a demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-date-picker)